# python at while loop IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, indexoutofrangeexception

```py
def solution(progresses, speeds):
    answer = []
    while len(progresses) != 0:
        count = 0
        for i in range(len(progresses)):
            if progresses[i] < 100:
                progresses[i] += speeds[i]
        while (progresses[0] >= 100) and (len(progresses) != 0):
            print("pop: ", progresses.pop(0))
            speeds.pop(0)
            count += 1
        if count != 0:
            answer.append(count)

    return answer


solution([93, 30, 55], [1, 30, 5])
```

my python terminal show me an error like this.

```
    while (progresses[0] >= 100) and (len(progresses) != 0):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

i dont know why this error comes up..... help me

Comment: Don't modify lists while you're iterating over them. You're `pop`ing everything off the list, eventually there's nothing left and then you have an index error at 0 because the list is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in other comments you should avoid modifying the list which is used in the `while` or `for` loop checks.

---

If you want to understand why your code is failing. The problem is this line:

```py
while (progresses[0] >= 100) and (len(progresses) != 0):
```

You are accessing element zero (`progresses[0]`) but the list is empty. If you swap the two checks, it works fine (because if the first check already returns `false` the second check is not performed at all).

```py
while (len(progresses) != 0 and progresses[0] >= 100):
```

Answer (score 1):

Agree with the comment. If you want, you can do `import copy` and `copy_of_speeds = copy.deepcopy(speeds)`, which will make a copy of the list that isn't tied to it, which you could loop over instead.

Your code also has the bug in the code, where

```
while progresses[0] >= 100:
            progresses.pop(0)
```

could potentially have `progresses` pop all the way to an empty list, and then `progresses[0]` hits that index error!. So if you do

`while len(progresses) > 0 && progresses[0] >= 100` instead, which won't hit that issue.

Comment: In the future, why not try printing information in your code as the code is running, which will mean that you can find out what's going on